# How are Laravel Group Filters able to get the values from a closure without a return

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am currently developing a system and I happened to run across a certain feature called in Laravel which I would like to know how it works.

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
  Route::get('user/account', 'UserController@account');
  Route::get('user/settings', 'UserController@settings');
  Route::get('post/create', 'PostController@create');
  Route::post('post/store', 'PostController@store');
  // ...
});
```

As can be seen from the code above Laravel is able to get all the internal routes without any of the routes needing to be returned.

How is this achieved?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done using a stack. Let's look at the `group()` method:

```
public function group(array $attributes, Closure $callback)
{
    $this->updateGroupStack($attributes);

    // Once we have updated the group stack, we will execute the user Closure and
    // merge in the groups attributes when the route is created. After we have
    // run the callback, we will pop the attributes off of this group stack.
    call_user_func($callback, $this);

    array_pop($this->groupStack);
}
```

First, the attributes you pass (like `'before' => 'auth'`) will be saved in `$this->groupStack`. After that the callback function is called.

Now when you for example do `Route::get()` the call will end up in `createRoute` which contains this section:

```
if ($this->hasGroupStack())
{
    $this->mergeGroupAttributesIntoRoute($route);
}
```

So if there are any group attributes, they will be merged with the route.

After the callback function of the group is executed the group attributes are removed from the stack with `array_pop`.

Comment: You're welcome ;) And actually you made mine bigger too. (Didn't know how it worked before I looked through the source either)